# Is there any option in TFS to get "List of files reviewed by a reviewer" and "History of reviewer for a file"?

Tags: tfs, tfs-code-review

Is there any way in TFS to get the below information

- List of files reviewed by a reviewer
- History of reviewer for a file

Does TFS has inbuilt in feature for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no these built-in features in TFS for now. You could add a uservoice [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services), TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion.

As a workaround, you could use TFS API and third-party tool  such as [linqpad](https://www.linqpad.net/) to collect related information. More details please go through this wonderful blog: [Getting Code Review Statistics Programmatically from TFS](http://www.geoffmazeroff.com/2016/04/10/getting-code-review-statistics-programmatically-from-tfs/)